# Pseudo-random function where the output is inverted using XOR

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

I'm looking to know whether or not this PRF is secure :

$$F'(k, x) = F(k, x) ⊕ 1^n$$

knowing that $F$ is already a secure PRF for

$$\{0, 1\}^n × \{0, 1\}^n → \{0, 1\}^n$$

with, for example, $n= 128$.

I would do it like this: knowing that $F$ is already a secure PRF, therefore an attacker cant know if the output of $F$ is a $0$ or a $1$.  When we have the XOR with $1^n$ , the advantage could go up to $1 \over 2$ (the attacker tries both possibilities, $0 ⊕ 1$ or $1 ⊕ 1$).

So I think this wouldn't be a secure PRF for that reason .

Comment: Please see the source code of my edit to see how you can use MathJax here on the site. Please review and enhance your question before posting, we're trying to be a relatively professional site, and we really should not have to bother with spelling mistakes that are easily caught by any spell check. Make your title as specific as possible.

Comment: Why do you think the advantage goes up to $1 \over 2$? Do you think the distribution of the output will be any different when XOR'ing the bits with one, which is basically the same as inverting the bits? What would happen if the attacker would perform the XOR himself?

Comment: Thank you for the edit @MaartenBodewes , i'm new to Stackexchange so i will try to enhance my questions with time. 
i'm still not sure about my answer(i'm new to the crypto course)  , so from what i understand from your comment is that inverting the bits wont make any change to the fact that the result prf is still secure?

Comment: Well, first of all I would like you to review what you said and try to figure out why you think it does make it less secure. This is obviously a question from a test or lesson and you did show that you tried to solve it yourself (which means it is welcome here), but instead of directly giving you the answer it seems more productive to let you reason it out, and *then* give the answer.

Comment: Yes , i understand that and respect it, it would actually help me more to understand the way it works  than to just have the answer , i think my way of trying to answer it was wrong though , now thinking about your first comment , if  $F$ is already a secure prf , inverting the result of its output wont change anything  about its security , the attacker still wont be able to guess the output because Reversing 0 and 1 leaves the advantage unchanged.

Comment: Right. So the only thing that remains it to write it up so that 1. it shows that it is still a PRF and 2. so that it is described in math as well. I'm not so great in those two parts though...

Comment: Thank you for your help @MaartenBodewes, i will proceed as it's shown in my course to write the advantage after the XOR and to prove that the result is still a secure $PRF$ .